# Cannot boot from USB or BIOS, grub rescue

Tags: grubrescue

I accidentally deleted my Linux partition from Windows, and when I restarted I always see the grub rescue screen. I did try setting root to each of the partitions, but I always got the unknown filesystem error. I found that the most suggested fix is to boot from a live CD/USB, but I can't perform that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Boot from live `Ubuntu` CD/USB, Install `GRUB2` in proper Partition 
To fix the problem.

this link fix my same problem.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

or if not correct it see 
http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

to manually install `GRUB2` in Terminal.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting a error because grub cannot find the linux. You need to boot into BIOS and manually select the boot option (USB). Once you do that re-install linux and it should update your grub config so that the new linux will be loaded

Comment: i'm trying to figure out how to boot from BIOS in my Lenovo laptop. I tried clicking "Esc" and all of the "F" keys but to no avail.

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/bios-setup-utility-access-keys-for-popular-computer-systems-2624463       try this. Slam those keys immediately